# Pick a random value from an enum?

Tags: java, random, enums

If I have an enum like this:

```
public enum Letter {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    //...
}
```

What is the best way to pick one randomly? It doesn't need to be production quality bulletproof, but a fairly even distribution would be nice.

I could do something like this

```
private Letter randomLetter() {
    int pick = new Random().nextInt(Letter.values().length);
    return Letter.values()[pick];
}
```

But is there a better way? I feel like this is something that's been solved before.

Comment: what do you think is wrong with your solution? It looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @GregS - the problem is that each call to `Letter.values()` has to create a new copy of the internal `Letter` value array.

Comment: Also not sure if you should be creating a new Random object each time you execute that function.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The only thing I would suggest is caching the result of `values()` because each call copies an array. Also, don't create a `Random` every time. Keep one. Other than that what you're doing is fine. So:

```
public enum Letter {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  //...

  private static final List<Letter> VALUES =
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
  private static final int SIZE = VALUES.size();
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  public static Letter randomLetter()  {
    return VALUES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you consider it useful, you can make an utility class for doing this. Something like RandomEnum<T extends Enum> with a constructor receiving the Class<T> for creating the list.

Comment: I really don't see the point of converting the `values()` array to an unmodifiable list.  The `VALUES` object is already encapsulated by virtue of being declared `private`.  It would be simpler AND more efficient to make it `private static final Letter[] VALUES = ...`.

Comment: Arrays in Java are mutable so if you have a array field and return it in a public method the caller can modify it and it modifies the private filed so you need to defensively copy the array. If you call that method lots of times it can be a problem so you put it in an immutable list instead to avoid unnecessary defensive copying.

Comment: @cletus: Enum.values() will return a new array on every invocation, so there is no need to wrap it before passing/using it in other places.

Comment: @Chii: it's precisely because it returns an array every time that you should create an immutable copy.

Comment: private static final Letter[] VALUES... is OK. It's private so it's inmmutable. You only need the public randomLetter() method which obviously returns a single value. Stephen C is right.

Comment: Arrays are mutable and it is just a way to prevent the array from being modifiable. Another option would be to have `Letter[] VALUES = values();` inside `randomLetter()` but this will remove the "caching" suggested in @cletus answer

Answer (score 169):

A single method is all you need for all your random enums:

```
    public static <T extends Enum<?>> T randomEnum(Class<T> clazz){
        int x = random.nextInt(clazz.getEnumConstants().length);
        return clazz.getEnumConstants()[x];
    }
```

Which you'll use:

```
randomEnum(MyEnum.class);
```

I also prefer to use [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) as:

```
private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was doing like the accepted answer and that left me with boilerplate code when I needed to randomize from my second Enum. Also, it's easy to forget about SecureRandom sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: You read my mind, exactly what I was looking for to add in my random entities generator test class. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 77):

Single line

```
return Letter.values()[new Random().nextInt(Letter.values().length)];
```

Comment: Simple and easy

Comment: Should be the most popular answer!

Comment: More efficient to not re-create the `Random` each time. Use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) instead. `Letter.values()[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(Letter.values().length)]`

Answer (score 49):

Combining the suggestions of [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) and [helios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9686/helios),

```
import java.util.Random;

public class EnumTest {

    private enum Season { WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL }

    private static final RandomEnum<Season> r =
        new RandomEnum<Season>(Season.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(r.random());
    }

    private static class RandomEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {

        private static final Random RND = new Random();
        private final E[] values;

        public RandomEnum(Class<E> token) {
            values = token.getEnumConstants();
        }

        public E random() {
            return values[RND.nextInt(values.length)];
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Oops, I forgot the bounded type parameter, `<E extends Enum<E>>`.

Comment: See also [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).

Comment: Very old answer I know, but shouldn't that be `E extends Enum<E>`?

Comment: @Lino: Edited for clarity; I don't think it's _required_ for correct type inference of the parameter bound, but I'd welcome correction; note also that `new RandomEnum<>(Season.class)` is permitted since Java 7.

Comment: This single `RandomEnum` class would be nice as a micro library, if you wanted to bundle it up and publish to central.

Answer (score 19):

### Simple Kotlin Solution

```
MyEnum.values().random()
```

`random()` is a default extension function included in base Kotlin on the `Collection` object. [Kotlin Documentation Link](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html)

#### If you'd like to simplify it with an extension function, try this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> random(): T = enumValues<T>().random()

// Then call
random<MyEnum>()
```

To make it static on your enum class. Make sure to import `my.package.random` in your enum file

```
MyEnum.randomValue()

// Add this to your enum class
companion object {
    fun randomValue(): MyEnum {
        return random()
    }
}
```

#### If you need to do it from an instance of the enum, try this extension

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> T.random() = enumValues<T>().random()

// Then call
MyEnum.VALUE.random() // or myEnumVal.random()
```

Comment: The question is not tagged as kotlin and is specifically about Java. While nice, this answer doesn't seem to apply to the question at hand.

Answer (score 11):

```
Letter lettre = Letter.values()[(int)(Math.random()*Letter.values().length)];
```

Answer (score 10):

Agree with Stphen C & helios. Better way to fetch random element from Enum is:

```
public enum Letter {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  //...

  private static final Letter[] VALUES = values();
  private static final int SIZE = VALUES.length;
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  public static Letter getRandomLetter()  {
    return VALUES[RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE)];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's probably easiest to have a function to pick a random value from an array.  This is more generic, and is straightforward to call.

```
<T> T randomValue(T[] values) {
    return values[mRandom.nextInt(values.length)];
}
```

Call like so:

```
MyEnum value = randomValue(MyEnum.values());
```

Answer (score 6):

Here a version that uses shuffle and streams

```
List<Direction> letters = Arrays.asList(Direction.values());
Collections.shuffle(letters);
return letters.stream().findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the most concise way of achieving your goal.All you need to do is to call `Letter.getRandom()` and you will get a random enum letter.

```
public enum Letter {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    //...

    public static Letter getRandom() {
        return values()[(int) (Math.random() * values().length)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do this for testing you could use [Quickcheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) ([this is a Java port I've been working on](https://quickcheck.dev.java.net/)).

```
import static net.java.quickcheck.generator.PrimitiveGeneratorSamples.*;

TimeUnit anyEnumValue = anyEnumValue(TimeUnit.class); //one value
```

It supports all primitive types, type composition, collections, different distribution functions, bounds etc. It has support for runners executing multiple values:

```
import static net.java.quickcheck.generator.PrimitiveGeneratorsIterables.*;

for(TimeUnit timeUnit : someEnumValues(TimeUnit.class)){
    //..test multiple values
}
```

The advantage of Quickcheck is that you can define tests based on a [specification](http://theyougen.blogspot.com/2009/06/defining-collectionadd-contract-in.html) where plain TDD works with scenarios.

Comment: looks intriguing. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: You can mail me if something does not work. You should use the 0.5b version.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that this single-line-return method is efficient enough to be used in such a simple job:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    FRIDAY;

    public static Day getRandom() {
        return values()[(int) (Math.random() * values().length)];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Day.getRandom());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It´s eaiser to implement an random function on the enum.

```
public enum Via {
    A, B;

public static Via viaAleatoria(){
    Via[] vias = Via.values();
    Random generator = new Random();
    return vias[generator.nextInt(vias.length)];
    }
}
```

and then you call it from the class you need it like this

```
public class Guardia{
private Via viaActiva;

public Guardia(){
    viaActiva = Via.viaAleatoria();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public Object getRandomFromEnum(Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz) {
    return clazz.values()[random.nextInt(clazz.values().length)];
}
```

Comment: did you actually try that? Enum does not have the values() method.

Answer (score 0):

enum ShapeColor {
Blue,
Yellow,
Red,
Green,
White,
}

```
    Random random=new Random();
    ShapeColor[] values=ShapeColor.values();
    int size=values.length;
    return values[random.nextInt(size)];
```

Comment: Can you explain how it works and why your answer fix the issue ?

Comment: Sure, let me explain.
First, we convert the enum into an array of the enum type. Now all values of the enum would be stored in an array. Then we generate a random int with max bound as the size of an array to generate a random index. Finally, after getting a random index, we access the value at that particular index from an array of the enum type.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static Letter randomLetter() {
    return List.of(values()).get(Random.randomInt(List.of(values()).size()));

}
```

Comment: Random.randomInt is not static