# How can I ensure user enters a valid choice?

Tags: java

I'm making a simple rock paper scissors program but am unsure how to ensure that the user only enters a valid choice. I need to be able to reprompt them if they don't type some varriant of "rock", "paper", or "scissors" (capitalization doesn't matter) and later "yes" or "no". Suggestions?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RockPaperScissors {

private int wins = 0;
private int losses = 0;
private int ties = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RockPaperScissors model = new RockPaperScissors();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors... Pick one! (Type Rock, Paper, or Scissors)");
        String playerChoice = scan.next();

        String computerChoice = model.getRandomChoice();

        System.out.println("You chose " + playerChoice + ".");
        System.out.println("The computer chose " + computerChoice + ".");

        RockPaperScissors.GameOutcome outcome = model.getGameOutcome(
                playerChoice, computerChoice);

        if (outcome == RockPaperScissors.GameOutcome.WIN) {
            System.out.println("You won! Congratulations");
        } else if (outcome == RockPaperScissors.GameOutcome.LOSE) {
            System.out.println("You lose! Better luck next time!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tie!");
        }

        System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (Yes/No):");

        String answer = scan.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
    System.out.println("Wins: " + model.getWins());
    System.out.println("Losses: " + model.getLosses());
    System.out.println("Ties: " + model.getTies());
    scan.close();
}

public static enum GameOutcome {
    WIN, LOSE, TIE;
}

public GameOutcome getGameOutcome(String userChoice, String computerChoice) {

    if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) {

        if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            losses++;
            return GameOutcome.LOSE;
        } else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) {
            wins++;
            return GameOutcome.WIN;
        }
    } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {

        if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) {
            losses++;
            return GameOutcome.LOSE;
        } else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) {
            wins++;
            return GameOutcome.WIN;
        }
    } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) {
        if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) {
            losses++;
            return GameOutcome.LOSE;
        } else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            wins++;
            return GameOutcome.WIN;
        }
    }
    ties++;
    return GameOutcome.TIE;
}

public String getRandomChoice() {
    double d = Math.random();

    if (d < .33) {
        return "Rock";
    } else if (d < .66) {
        return "Paper";
    } else {
        return "Scissors";

    }
}

public int getWins() {
    return wins;
}

public int getLosses() {
    return losses;
}

public int getTies() {
    return ties;
}
```

}

Comment: Create a loop that continuously grabs user input until he/she enters something valid. Once the user has entered a correct answer, leave the loop

Comment: @VinceEmigh how can I make this work regardless of capitalization, though?

Comment: Use `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` when comparing user input to the valid choices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to play a session of *roshambo* against the computer, I'd like to be able to make my selection by only typing in the first letter of "Rock" , "Paper" or "Scissors".

Using a rich `enum` is a natural choice here:

```
private enum Choice {

    ROCK ("Rock"),
    PAPER ("Paper"),
    SCISSORS ("Scissors");

    private String displayName;

    private static final List<Choice> VALUES =
            Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
          private static final int SIZE = VALUES.size();
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();        

    private Choice(String dn) {
        displayName = dn;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random Choice.
     */
    public static Choice getRandomChoice() {
        return VALUES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Choice that matches the input string. The input is considered a match if it starts with the same character 
     * as the displayname of a Choice. If no match is found, returns null.
     */
    public static Choice fromInput(String input) {

        if (input == null || input.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        for (Choice c : VALUES) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(c.displayName.charAt(0))
                    == Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(0))) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the text to display to the user, asking for input to #fromInput().
     */
    public static String promptText() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Choice c : VALUES) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(c.displayName).append(" (")
                    .append(c.displayName.charAt(0)).append(")");
        }
        sb.append(". Pick one!");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Having most of the functionality coded declaratively in the `enum`, your client code will become much simpler. The `enum` also handles the computer's random selection (idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972399/905488) answer).

```
 while (true) {

        Choice choice = null;

        while (choice == null) {
            System.out.println(Choice.promptText());
            choice = Choice.fromInput(scan.next());
        }

        String computerChoice = Choice.getRandomChoice().displayName;
 // ...
```

You could also encapsulate most (if not all) of the logic you have in the `getGameOutcome` method, into `Choice`.

Answer (score 5):

Keep the valid choices in a list, loop asking the input from the user until he enter something valid.

```
List<String> validChoices = Arrays.asList("rock", "paper", "scissors");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = null;
do
{
    System.out.println("Enter a choice (rock|paper|scissors)");
    choice = sc.next().toLowerCase();//Retrieve as lower case
}
while(!validChoices.contains(choice));
```

Comment: `toLowerCase()` creates a new `String` object. Probably best just to compare using `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: @VinceEmigh `equalsIgnoreCase` use `regionMatches` which call `toUpperCase`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Note that I still prefer `equalsIgnoreCase` as it have some optimization such as checking the length, and comparing by ref for character literal. However, In my example I dont even use `equals` but instead check if the list contains the string.

Comment: @avgvstvs Why not always take the better way ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Somesing like

```
if (!playerChoise.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && ...) continue;
```

Or you can store valid choises in list as shown above, and use foreach loop. But it will be more difficult, becouse you need to check all variants. Maybe something like.

```
private boolean checkValid(String userChoise, String... variants) {
    for (String s : variants) {
        if (playerChoise.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call it for both cases:

```
if (!checkValid(userChoise, "rock", "papper", "scissors")) continue;
```