# How to Random Choice element from Enum Scala3

Tags: scala, random, enums, scala-3

My problem is very simple. I have the following:

```scala
enum Colors:
  case Blue, Red, Green
```

How can I choose a random element from this enum? I tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972392/pick-a-random-value-from-an-enum) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Random.nextInt` to generate an index of a random enum value.

This avoids shuffling the `Array` of values, and generates only one random number.

```
import scala.util.Random

enum Colors:
  case Blue, Red, Green

object Colors:
  private final val colors = Colors.values

  def random: Colors = colors(Random.nextInt(colors.size))

@main def run: Unit =
  println(Colors.random)
```

Answer (score 2):

```scala
enum Colors:
  case Blue, Red, Green

@main def run: Unit = 
  import scala.util.Random

  val mycolor = Colors.values

  println(Random.shuffle(mycolor).head)
```